# LoadError: cannot load such file -- watir/WindowHelper

Tags: watir

```
irb(main):011:0> require 'watir/WindowHelper'

LoadError: cannot load such file -- watir/WindowHelper from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:i    
n `require' from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:i    
n `rescue in require'from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:i    
n `require'from (irb):11 from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I get this error while trying

```
require 'watir/WindowHelper'
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens and the solution for it?
I am not able to handle the IE pop up while clicking on a link to download files.

Comment: What version of Watir are you using? I do not believe that WindowHelper is in the latest version.

Comment: I am using Watir 3.0.0. Ruby 1.9.3. Oh!!! in that case how should I handle this pop up in this version??? is it better to use the previous version???which version???

Answer (score 0):

The Watir wiki has a bunch of examples with working with popups - http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Pop+Ups.